# libclang.dll cannot be found

Tags: python, c++, clang, libclang

I have installed the clang python library on windows. When I'm executing a script that uses it, It gives me this:

```
Could not find module 'path\to\clang\libclang.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.. To provide a path to libclang use Config.set_library_path() or Config.set_library_file().
```

Despite the fact that I included in my code

```
from clang.cindex import Config 
Config.set_library_path('path/to/clang/libclang.dll')
```

when I checked the path of clang, I couldn't find `ibclang.dll` or `ibclang.so`.
Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: have you tried using an absolute path rather than a relative one in `set_library_path`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I'm using an absolute path. I think the problem is that the file `libclang.dll` can't be found under the clang folder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build clang and get the `libclang.dll`, the pre-built version can be downloaded [here](https://ziglang.org/deps/llvm+clang+lld-10.0.0-x86_64-windows-msvc-release-mt.tar.xz).

Put `libclang.dll` into the same directory as your script and do this:

```py
import os

scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
cindex.Config.set_library_path(scriptDir)
```